# Handling IE8/IE9 XDomainRequest POST request on a Rails 4 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, rails-api

You can't edit the content-type on IE8/IE9 XDR requests. Each request that I make is sending content-type: "text/plain" while my Rails API is look for "application/json". My Rails API isn't recognizing the data that I'm sending and not parsing it into parameters in the controller. XHR is working, but I need to do cross domain requests. What do I need to change in my Rails API to handle the request?

working:

```
function xhrPost(url, data, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

not working:

```
function xdrPost(url, data, callback) {
  var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
  xdr.onload = function () {
    callback(xdr.responseText);
  };
  xdr.open('POST', url, true);
  xdr.send(data);
}
```

controller:

```
module API
  module V1
    class MyController < ActionController::API
      def my_action
        puts params #=> my data isn't parsed when using XDR
        render :json => { :message => 'Success' }, :status => :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you find the fix for this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @mikeLspohn, I added my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most robust solution, but I was able to handle XDR requests by checking the content_type and manually extracting the post params. This can probably be beefed up and moved elsewhere if you need to use it all the time. In my case I only needed it for a single action.

```
module API
  module V1
    class MyController < ActionController::API
      def my_action

        # Handle IE8/IE9 XDR requests
        unless request.content_type == 'application/json' || request.content_type == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(request.raw_post)
        end

        # Processing...

        render :json => { :message => 'Success' }, :status => :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```